# Why can I not use HasOne() when pointing to an owned Entity Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I have an Aggregate Root (Product) with, amongst others, a list of Value Objects (ProductIdentifiers). In order to store this list of Value Objects in a separate database table, I use EF Core 2.2's `OwnsMany()` method. A different AR (Device) also has a list of Value Objects (Device Identifiers).  the DeviceIdentifier's model, I want to point to ProductIdentifier to make clear what type of identifier it is. When I just incorporate this in my model, I get an error when adding a migration: `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'DeviceIdentifier.ProductIdentifier' of type 'ProductIdentifier'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

It looks like the migration manager does not know what I want with the property `ProductIdentifier`. Hence, I decided to use Fluent API to make clear that `DeviceIdentifier` "has one" ProductIdentifier (or at least, uses it). Hence, I added the line `deviceIdentifier.HasOne(d => d.ProductIdentifier);`. But then, when I try to run the migration manager, I get the following error: `The relationship from 'DeviceIdentifier.ProductIdentifier' to 'ProductIdentifier' is not supported because the owned entity type 'ProductIdentifier' cannot be on the principal side of a non-ownership relationship.`

Why is this? Is it not possible to point from a model's property to another model's property if the other model is owned by an entity/aggregate root?

[Here you can see an image of what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3P0c.png). I am unable to create the red line!

Comment: hello @ydg. i have same issue. had you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding what your problem is but in your context, override the `OnModelCreating` and you can code the relation between your entities.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<X>().HasOne(x => x.Y);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Z>().HasMany(x => x.X).WithOne(y=>y.Z);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to do this since HasMany() cannot be used when pointing to a Value Object (that is DDD terminology). Value Objects don't have ID's so they need to have a composite key when storing an array of Value Objects in a database table (see this link: https://www.nankov.com/posts/improved-support-value-objects-ef-core-22). Hence, I have to use OwnsMany(), which leads to the problem at hand...

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking of nested owned types?

If so check the docs [Nested owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#nested-owned-types). Basically its same for entities, bu you use `OwnsOne` to set the relation between owned types.

`HasOne` is for entities and opposite of `HasMany`. For owned entities it's `OwnsOne` and `OwnsMany`.